# Object type error when copying a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open a file stored in a fixed location in the desktop and copy a certain sheet to the current workbook.

I get Error 438.

```
Sub RangeCheckFormula()

Dim TargetFile As Workbook
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet

Set TargetFile = ActiveWorkbook

ActiveSheet.Range("F1") = "#"
ActiveSheet.Range("G1") = "CLUSTER"
ActiveSheet.Range("H1") = "PROFILE"

Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Outlet List"

Set TargetSheet = ActiveSheet

Application.Workbooks.Open (Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED 
FILES\" & "UPDATED_OUTLET_LIST")
CurrentSheet.Copy Before:=TargetFile.TargetSheet.Range("A1")

Workbooks("UPDATED_OUTLET_LIST.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Does UPDATED_OUTLET_LIST not have a file extension such as xlsx/xlsm ?  If your desktop is configured to hide extensions for known file types I would recommend turning that option off.

Comment: It does. .xlsx . That file opens fine with the code by the way. it's at `currentsheet.copy` that i get the error..

Comment: Glad you got the answer you're after.  Quick question though - what is `Error 438`?   It makes life easier to include the description as well as the error number.  **Edit:** Ignore that.... it's the question title. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is

```
Application.Workbooks.Open (Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\" & "UPDATED_OUTLET_LIST.xlsx")
ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=TargetFile.Sheets(TargetSheet.Name)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! This way i don't need to be storing the active sheet name in a variable too!. Thank you!